# Some extras of my Intent are missing

Tags: java, android

I have two activities and I am trying to pass some data from one activity to another which shows some strange behavior. I am getting data of some keys at the other activity but some of them are missing(null).

I am getting `mStartStopInfo` and `mVehicleRide` whereas the other 2 keys are missing from the bundle.

Here's the code which starts the other activity:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConfirmationActivity.class);

    String startStopInfo = String.format("%s - %s", mVehicleRide.getStartStopInfo().getDepartureTime(), mVehicleRidesFromStopsResponse.getStartStopName());
    String endStopInfo   = String.format("%s - %s", mVehicleRide.getEndStopInfo().getDepartureTime(), mVehicleRidesFromStopsResponse.getEndStopName());

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(INTENT_KEY_START_STOP_INFO, startStopInfo);
    bundle.putString(INTENT_KEY_END_STOP_INFO, endStopInfo);
    bundle.putParcelable(INTENT_KEY_ROUTE_STOP_INFO, mVehicleRide);
    bundle.putString(INTENT_KEY_RIDE_DATE, mVehicleRidesFromStopsResponse.getDate());
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Following is the code which collects the data in other activity:

```
@Override
protected void initData(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(bundle == null){
            finish();
        }

        mStartStopInfo = bundle.getString(INTENT_KEY_START_STOP_INFO);
        mEndStopInfo = bundle.getString(INTENT_KEY_END_STOP_INFO);
        mVehicleRide = bundle.getParcelable(INTENT_KEY_ROUTE_STOP_INFO);
        mDate = bundle.getString(INTENT_KEY_RIDE_DATE);

     }
}
```

Is there something which is wrong?

EDIT: I am also getting the following exception:

```
W/ArrayMap: New hash 0 is before end of array hash 235905106 at index 2 key 

java.lang.RuntimeException: here
at android.util.ArrayMap.append(ArrayMap.java:547)
at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3046)
at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:257)
at android.os.BaseBundle.getBoolean(BaseBundle.java:825)
at android.content.Intent.getBooleanExtra(Intent.java:6914)
at io.branch.referral.Branch.checkIntentForSessionRestart(Branch.java:2540)
at io.branch.referral.Branch.access$1100(Branch.java:73)
at io.branch.referral.Branch$BranchActivityLifeCycleObserver.onActivityStarted(Branch.java:2460)
at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityStarted(Application.java:236)
at android.app.Activity.onStart(Activity.java:1258)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:552)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:177)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1412)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7015)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2909)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3046)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1688)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what could be wrong with this small amount of code. Are you sure the values aren't `null` *before* you add them to the intent? Are the values of the correct type? Are they keys you are using static members of one class, or did you duplicate the keys in each `Activity` (which would be prone to errors)?

Comment: There is lack of code. Are all keys unique? Also, instead of declaring soo many keys why are not implementing Parcelable on the VehicleRide class.

Comment: Isn't it redundant to pass both your whole mVehicleRide object and start and stop time as well? Also, I would recommend to store dates as utc timestamp, e.g. a Long, instead of a string

Comment: @Bryan The values are non null before I put them in. The types are also correct and the keys are statically imported from a different class.

Comment: @A.Kuchinke The date is a formatted date which is intentionally in String because it is being used only for representation.

Answer (score 0):

> Your information is not enough, but my assumption is wrong variable
>   types.(if the other parts are correct)

Check your variable types you put as extras. You are trying to get all your extras via:

```
getStringExtra()
```

In your case; If any of your extra data type is different than String, they will be null.

For example; if your variable type is **integer** you must get this data via:

```
getIntExtra()
```

Comment: They are String only.

Comment: @SudhanshuMishra then you should provide more info & code. We cannot solve your problem with just assumptions.